# Disable Grails from automatically setting values in relations

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Here is the case, I have two domains whose relative bits are as follows

```
    Subcription {
        BillingPeriod billingPeriod

        static constraints = {                                 
            billingPeriod nullable: true
        }   
    }

    BillingPeriod {            
        Subcription subcription

        static constraints = {                                 
            subscription nullable: true
        }   
    }
```

There are other fields in the domains but I have omitted those as they are not needed for this question.

What I am doing is getting a Subscription and creating a new BillingPeriod with that Subcription. Here is the code

```
    Subscription subscription = Subscription.get(id)
    BillingPeriod billingPeriod = new BillingPeriod(subscription: subscription)
    billingPeriod.save()
```

Now the problem is that when the subscription was retrieved at line 1 it's billingPeriod was null. But just after the line 2 gets executed or the new BillingPeriod instance is created with that subscription, the subscription's billingPeriod changes from null to the newly created billingPeriod!

How can stop/disable this two way relationship from being constructed automatically?

I am using Grails 2.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GORM works exactly the way it was designed.

In your case, there's a join-table between `Subcription` and `BillingPeriod`, which holds 1 record for 2 instances of your domain classes. That means, that if you create an instance of one class and fill the reference to the instance of another class, then the join-record is created and becomes visible to the second class as well.

This is what you see and is the desired behavior.

If you don't want to have it that way, you must decouple your classes. One of the possible way would be to use the `hasOne` and a read-only `formula`:

```
Subcription {
  BillingPeriod getBillingPeriod(){
    BillingPeriod.findBySubscription this
  }
}

BillingPeriod {            
  static hasOne = [ subcription:Subcription ]
}
```

`hasOne` doesn't create the join table, it's using the FK-column.